# How to create an iterator for nested structure behind Rc<>s?

Tags: rust

consider some code like this:

```rust
struct Foo {
    parent: Option<Weak<Foo>>,
    some_collection: BTreeMap<u32, u32>,
}

struct Container {
   items: RefCell<Vec<Rc<Foo>>>,
}

struct Ref<'a> {
   container: &'a Container,
   foo: Rc<Foo>,
}
```

I need mutability so the items are wrapped in a `RefCell`.
Because I can otherwise not get references to `Foo`s I put them inside an `Rc`.

Since `Foo` is highly dependent on the container type to do anything useful I wrapped references to foos in a `Ref<>` structure.
This works fine as long I can store the reference structure somewhere.

What I want to do now, is implement an Iterator which iterates over `Foo`s collections along their parent relationship.

This is failing gloriously because I cannot store a reference to the iterator of `Foo::some_collection` while dropping the `Rc` (or moving the `Rc` alongside the iterator).

I know this is a similar issue to several "Can I store a reference to the same thing in one struct" questions. They, however do not prove to be very helpful because I do not know what else to do in that case.

How can I solve this?

To clarify I need an iterator which does something like this:

```rust
struct MyIterator<'a> {
    iter: std::collections::btree_map::Iter<'a, u32, u32>,
    foo: Ref<'a>,
}

impl<'a> Iterator for MyIterator<'a> {
    type Item = (&'a u32, &'a u32);

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if let Some(item) = self.iter.next() {
            Some(item)
        } else if (/*retrieve parent*/) {
            self.iter = parent.some_collection.iter();
            self.next()
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that `Option<Weak<Foo>>` is redundant: you can use simply `Weak<Foo>` and assign `Weak::new()` instead of `None` when you don't have a value.

Answer (score 0):

I resorted to a work-around with unsafe code:

I replaced `Rc<Foo>` with `Pin<Box<Foo>>` and simply cast the lifetime of the reference to the container lifetime. This is possible in my case because my container will not remove items only add them.

```rust
impl Container {
    fn get_ref(&'a self, i: usize) -> &'a Foo {
        let items = self.items.borrow();
        let pinned = &items[i];

        // This is safe because the foo is pinned 
        // and the reference does not outlive the container
        // and we do not remove any foos
        unsafe { std::mem::transmute::<&'_ Foo, &'a Foo>(pinned.as_ref().get_ref()) }
    }
}
```

Now that we have actual reference we do not have the problem of locally dropped objects because the references outlive the scope they are obtained in.
This way implementing the iterators is trivial.